# allowing code blocks in a sharpoint aspx site page in one directory only

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, development, aspx

I have this section in my web.config

```
<PageParserPaths>
    <PageParserPath VirtualPath="/*" CompilationMode="Always" AllowServerSideScript="true" IncludeSubFolders="true" />
</PageParserPaths>
```

what i would like is to restrict the virtual path further to

```
VirtualPath="/SitePages/DataDictionary/*"
```

but when I enter that I get the

> Sorry, something went wrong  An error occurred during the processing
>   of /SitePages/DataDictionary/default.aspx. Code blocks are not allowed
>   in this file.

message switching back to

```
VirtualPath="/*"
```

works ? how do I format it to only allow coded pages in that one directory?

Comment: try to start he Path from site collection  VirtualPath="Sites/sitename/SitePages/DataDictionary/*"

Comment: Thanks Waqas I am not sure what to use this folder is in my "root"/main site to to access it i type http://spdev.mysite.com/SitePages/DataDictionary/default.aspx

Comment: you site url is http://sitenam.com or http://sitename.com/sites/name?

Comment: http//spdev.mysite.com/SitePages/DataDictionary/default.aspx    the DataDictionary is just a folder I created in teh sitepages collection to isolate the pages with codeblocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the ~ is what got things working

```
  <PageParserPaths>
    <PageParserPath VirtualPath="~/SitePages/DataDictionary/*" CompilationMode="Always" AllowServerSideScript="true" IncludeSubFolders="true"/>
    <PageParserPath VirtualPath="~/sites/RDS/SitePages/DataDictionary/*" CompilationMode="Always" AllowServerSideScript="true" IncludeSubFolders="true"/>
  </PageParserPaths>
```